# Finding and patching OpenSSL Apache on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, openssl

I have seen that they have released updates for OpenSSL.  I am running a Apache on Windows.  If I run "OpenSSL version" it reports "OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014".

This was a complete solution install, so I'm not clear if OpenSSL is running or not.  I cannot find it in processes.  I do see httpd.exe running mod_ssl.so.  I followed the vendor's howto to create and install a certificate with OpenSSL, so I know OpenSSL exists on the server, I'm just not sure if it is being used.  SSL web connections to it are working.

How can I tell if OpenSSL is running, what version is live, and how do I patch a Windows implementation?

Comment: If its a complete solution install openssl could be embedded and you might not see it running. The only way to upgrade this would be to see if the vendor has a patch or a newer version.

Comment: What is this `complete solution install`?

Comment: It looks like the OpenSSL binary distributions for Windows are updated - https://www.openssl.org/about/binaries.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to the site you originally downloaded whatever it is you have.  See if they have provided an update.  If not, then bug them to provide an updated 'complete solution'.

Since you referred to this as a 'complete solution', I am guessing you didn't compile this on your own, so there really isn't much you can do on your own unless you stop using something that was built for you, and rebuild everything from source.

Comment: In addition to that, stop using Apache on Windows in business systems.